# How to grant permission for application which is downloaded from play store?

Tags: android, shell, permissions, adb, dumpsys

Already I know google denied this dump permission except system applications from version 4.1 and more.

But still I can able to grant this dump permission using following command for debuggable applications.,

command :

> adb shell pm grant "com.packageName" android.permission.DUMP

But i cannot do the same for the applications which is downloaded from play store,

command :

> adb shell pm grant "com.playStoreApp" android.permission.DUMP

error :

> Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Package
>   com.playStoreApp has not requested permission android.permission.DUMP

Is there is any hack or work around to grant permission for play store apps?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Is there is any hack or work around to grant permission for play store apps?" -- not on an ordinary device. On a rooted device, perhaps. `DUMP` is a `signature|system|development` permission, in terms of `protectionLevel`. `development` is what's allowing you to adjust the value of the debuggable app. `system` means the app is installed on the system partition, which is possible if you root your device and move the app there.

Answer (score 4):

There is not a workaround. android.permission.Dump is protected by system, signature, and development permission protection levels. Line 1993 of [the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-mr1-release/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml) shows you this. If your APK is signed with the framework cert, is in the priv-app directory, or debuggable (see below) you can use the pm service to grant the permission, but otherwise the code specifically prevents what you're asking for (line 2624 of [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-mr1-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java)).

Debuggable APKs can be created through setting the debuggable attribute on a buildType via build.gradle. Sample Android DSL:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            ...
        }
        quality_assurance {
            debuggable true
        }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I´m trying to set animation with this https://gist.github.com/danielgomezrico/9371a79a7222a156ddad but I´m getting `Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE is not a changeable permission type` why?

Comment: Are you on Android M Preview?

Comment: Specifically, is your device running the preview?

Comment: The bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2557